# Python unittest import problems

Tags: python, unit-testing, package

I'm having a tough time understanding packages, and specifically how to use unittest with packages. I looked at this question () but the correct answer to that question didn't solve my problem. I have the following structure:

```
model
|-- __init__.py
|-- boardmodel.py
|
|-- exceptions
|   |
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- exceptions.py
|
|-- test
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- test_boardmodel.py
```

With the following files/imports:

**model/__init__.py:**

```
import model.exceptions.exceptions
import model.boardmodel
```

**model/exceptions/__init__.py:**

*contains nothing*

**model/test/__init__.py:**

*contains nothing*

imports inside **boardmodel.py:**:

```
from model.exceptions.exceptions import ZeroError, OverlapError, ArgumentError, ProximityError
```

imports inside **test_boardmodel.py:**

```
import unittest

from model.boardmodel import Board, Ball, Wall
from model.exceptions.exceptions import ProximityError
```

I place myself in the model-directory and I run `python -m unittest test.test_boardmodel.py`. I get the following message:

```
ERROR: test_boardmodel (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: test_boardmodel
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 153, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/pythonfun/BouncingBalls/balls/src/model/test/test_boardmodel.py", line 3, in <module>
    from model.boardmodel import Board, Ball, Wall
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'model'
```

I'm a bit lost with how the imports work and what location the modules/packages are looked for when an import statement is executed. Why isn't `model` found?

I shall add that if I remove `model.` from all the imports listed, the tests work, but I can't use the package from "outside" anymore:

```
src
|-- visual.py
|
|-- model
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- boardmodel.py
    |
    |-- exceptions
    |   |
    |   |-- __init__.py
    |   |-- exceptions.py
    |
    |-- test
        |-- __init__.py
        |-- test_boardmodel.py
```

inside **visual.py:**

```
import model
from model.boardmodel import Board
```

Answer (score 12):

I was facing the same issue, being able to import some modules from several files, but not from a test file, so I saw this solution:

> If you have test/my_test.py, tests should be run as:
>
> ```
> python -m test.my_test
> ```

After that, I imported what I wanted and got no errors.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding the following above your import statements:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "..")))
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe the standard package structure is

```
  myproject
  ├── myproject
  ├── tests
  └── scripts
```

If you want to run the test without installing the package, run them from the top `myproject` folder so that `import myproject` will succeed in your tests.  (Similarly for the scripts.) For this to work, use absolute imports or explicit relative imports in `myproject`.